# Are these possible with LightSwitch with a SharePoint Online 2013 List Data source?

Tags: html, sharepoint-2013, custom-lists, lightswitch-2013

1. On a browse screen connected to a SharePoint List data, How complicated to drive data item selected from a query string value like ?ID=xx? Where would that logic go?
2. What's the best way to add hard coded text to a detail browse  page?
3. What's the best way to NOT display field names on a detail browse page?  Don't see a option in the controls.
4. What's the best way to add page formatting like a horizontal divide line and a fancy border around a screen?
5. Add a buttons that redirects pass a query string with data concatenated from the data source?
6. Join multiple SharePoint Lists into one screen?
7. Add a button that approves a List Item.